# How to create identity provider for single sign-in in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, single-sign-on, idp

I have a NestJS app with authorization mechanism that uses JWT and stores them in cookies.
All users are stored in a database (mongo).
I want to connect an external support desk service using SSO, so users that are logged into our app can use this external service.
How can you create an identity provider?
I am especially interested in SAML, because our current support desk choice supports only this flavour of SSO.
But we are still open to replace it with another one.
Any suggestions? May be you have some links on useful resources?
Thanks.